# Why additional characters appear when String in Java to HTML file?

Tags: java, html, tags, special-characters

I've looked through "similar" questions but wasn't able to get an answer to mine. Please point me to one if it already exists.

Problem: when saving String/StringBuilder to HTML format it adds additional characters at the beginning of the page and I can't figure out why. Example:

```
¬ítX<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

method:

```
public void saveToHTML(){
    String fileName = "";
    if (docName != null){
        fileName += docName;
    } else {
        fileName += stdFileName;
    }
    fileName += "HTML.html";
    String tempText = new String("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\t<body>");
    int tabCount = 3;                                                                                       
    for (int oneSec = 0; oneSec < allSections.size(); oneSec++){
        for (int onePar = 0; onePar < allSections.get(oneSec).getCountParagraphs(); onePar++){
            tempText += (convertParToHTML(allSections.get(oneSec).getParagraph(onePar), 
                                             tabCount));        
        }
    }
    tempText += ("\n\t</body>\n</html>");
    serializeDoc(fileName, tempText.toString());
}
```

serializeDoc() below:

```
/**
 * Helper method to serialize files
 * 
 * @param fileName name of the file to be saved with
 * @param object object to be saved in the file
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void serializeDoc(String fileName, Object object){
    try {
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        out.writeObject(object);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
      System.out.println("The file couldn't be created");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `serializeDoc`?

Comment: ObjectOutputStream performs *Java serialization,* which is not the same as writing text.  Use [Files.writeString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString%28java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted `serializeDoc` so we really can't say. But this I will tell you: You really need to keep track of your charset with text files. Outputting the same text in ascii, latin-1, utf-8, utf-16, etc will give you different file sizes and different results. The best way to ensure conformity is to use FileWriters and FileReaders, where you can declare the charset type

-- update --

Yikes yikes and YIKES! You do NOT want to use object serialization here. This is going to save your java objects directly to the file, making the file harder to read and manually adjust. Writing the bytes to the FileOutputStream would be better, but like I said the best solution would be FileWriter so that you can specify the charset to save in.

Comment: added the serializeDoc() for visibility. It really just uses the regular serialization to save the doc, not really adding any characters. Additionally, special characters only appear in the first line. I will try the FileWriter to see if it makes a difference